# Merge request for MCAS purpose questions

Tags: support, merge

It is accepted ([Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/392799)) that duplicate closing can apply to a older question, i.e. vote to close the older if the newer post is better (Q and/or A).

In lieu of that, in [Closing an earlier post as a duplicate of a later one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1375/392799), Jeff Atwood simply answered:

> Just merge them.

I'm not sure what's the current stance (here) on merging. I've seen it done just the once [back in Nov 2016](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/6280/timeline).

Long story short, can we merge those:

- [What is MCAS trying to fix on B737 MAX?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/66799/14897) (to be main)
- [Why the need for the MCAS on the Boeing 737 Max 8?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/63781/14897)
- [What is MCAS' purpose?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/81646/14897)

In this particular case, it would (not sure if diplomatic hat is on or off) mitigate the useless bumping of the posts with the lower-scored answers with "new" unsubstantiated insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Urgh what a mess. I have taken the following actions

1. Merged [Why the need for the MCAS on the Boeing 737 Max 8?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/63781/14897) into [What is MCAS trying to fix on B737 MAX?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/66799/14897)
2. Left [What is MCAS' purpose?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/81646/14897) as duplicate of [What is MCAS trying to fix on B737 MAX?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/66799/14897) as it came much later and was already closed as duplicate

I didn't see much benefit in the final merge, but if anyone feels super strongly about it post a comment and I might rethink.